Error Handling in Spring boot kafka in Batch Listener
Working on a Spring boot application where it listens to Kafka a topic, processes, and inserts to DB. Currently, we are manually acknowledging the messages and using batchlistener as true. We are getting a batch of 500 messages once to process, using for loop to process each message put into DB and then acknowledge the message to Kafka.
I have used ExponentialBackOff for re-tries, like if DB is down, the current message out of 500 messages, should try for "N" no.of times and finally go to "CommonErrorHandler" and log the message.
The problem here is,
If there is any error in the 500th event, again the whole batch of 500 tries to re-process, which is not acceptable.
To resolve it, started throwing BatchListenerFailedException with index, instead of just Exception. But it introduces another problem in that, it's not trying for N number of times, as soon as control goes to catch block with BatchListenerFailedException, it goes to the common error handler and skips the event.
Another issue is, out of 500 records, if the 101st record fails, again it's processing 500 records from the beginning when we call backoff, though we have acknowledged the first 100 messages already. How can I correct it?
Note: I read somewhere that though we give Manual or Manual immediate, the batch will commit the acknowledgment once all the messages are completed. Please correct.
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
try{
    acknowledgement.acknowledge();

}catch(Exception e){

throw e; // Option 1 - If we throw direct exception, its trying while batch again
throw new BatchListenerFailedException("Failed", i); // Option 2 - If we throw it, its not trying for "N" no.of times, directly skipping and going to next record.
   }
}

